# $x+y=156[ x+z=183$; $y+z=139:$ what is value of $x, y, z$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Please can you help a dad teach his daughter the following problem:
$x+y=156,. 
x+z=183 ,, 
y+z=139 $

What is value of x and y and z?

I do not know the type of equation to search "how to"!!

Apologies if this is very simple

Comment: Easiest here is to subtract the second equation from the first, and then add the third after which only $\ y\ $ remains as a variable.

Comment: This is a system of linear equations.

Comment: But maybe another method is supposed to be used. In this case, please give more context.

Comment: So to add more context...Liam has these three shapes.

Three shapes X, Y and Z

He uses them to make different towers. He measures the height of each tower he makes. Four towers created with the shapes

Tower one length  x+y=156cm
Tower two length x+z=183cm 
Tower three length y+z=139cm

Liam stacks all three shapes to make one tall tower. How tall is the tower?

I hope this helps

Comment: I have watch several videos on system of linear equations and I cannot get my head around it because none of the examples they use seem to apply.

Please would you be kind enough to type the working out for me so I can follow? I do not want just the answer I want yo be able to understand it so I can teach my daughter. I appreciate this is probably very simple for you guys but I am struggling to teach her with the schools closed.

Comment: Thank you to every one who was kind enough to respond and help an 'out of his depth' dad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do here is to take combinations of these equations in order to eliminate variables, like so:

If we call $x+y=156$ equation 1, $x+z =183$ equation 2 and $y+z=139$ equation 3 then subtracting equation 2 from equation 1 gives us $y-z = -27$ (we literally just subtract the LHS of equation 2 from equation 1 and the same for the RHS), call this equation 4.

Then we have equation 3 saying $y+z =139$, and equation 4 saying $y-z = -27$. So equation 2 + equation 4 (again just add the LHS and RHS of the equations) gives us $2y = 112$, so $y=56$.

Then take $y=56$ and substitute it into equation 1 to find $x=100$, and find $z=83$ using your new found $x,y$ values and the other equations (just pick whichever is easier).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant thank you very very much. 
Is there a name/theory for this kind of equation?

Comment: @Paul my pleasure! Yea, if you google "system of linear equations" or "solving simultaneous equations" then you will find lots of resources on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

After you realize $x+y+z=0.5((x+y)+(y+z)+(z+x)),$ it should be easy to find $x,y,z.$

Answer (score 0):

Add all the equations to get, 
$$2x+2y+2z = 156 + 183 + 139 $$
$$\therefore x+y+z = 239$$
You can use this to solve for $x$, $y$, $z$ by substituting the values of $y+z$, $z+x$, $x+y$